# Rebuilding Django development server database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to reset my django database so I've run `manage.py sqlflush` and run that output in MySQL.

I've then run `manage.py flush`.  I think this should clear everything.

I've then run `manage.py makemigrations` which seemed to identify all tables that would need building but when I run `manage.py migrate` it says nothing needs doing and so I now don't have any tables when I run my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlflush` command as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlflush):

> Prints the SQL statements that would be executed for the flush command.

For example running the `sqlflush` command on a newly created project give the output:

```
DELETE FROM "auth_user_user_permissions";
DELETE FROM "auth_group_permissions";
DELETE FROM "auth_permission";
DELETE FROM "auth_user_groups";
DELETE FROM "auth_user";
DELETE FROM "django_admin_log";
DELETE FROM "django_content_type";
DELETE FROM "auth_group";
DELETE FROM "django_session";
```

But this does not actually delete the database tables. To delete the tables you will need to then run the command:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

You will then need to run the output of `sqlflush` within that shell.

Comment: Quote from question: "so I've run `manage.py sqlflush` and **run that output in MySQL**. "

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the `migrations` folder inside your app folder. You should also delete the database file, if there is one (for SQLite there is a file called `db.sqlite3` in the root project folder, but I'm not sure how this works for MySQL). Then run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.